# Google Analytics - Existing UA

Tags: google-analytics

I created a new user in Google Analytics and wanted to know if it is possible to retrieve the information from an existing UA in another account. I had a lot of information in the old user (referring to a site) and wanted to know if it is possible to retrieve this information for the new user. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to transfer the data from an old UA number/account to the new one? 
Transferring data from one UA number to another is unfortunately not possible. If you just mean you have two users you can add the user to both Accounts and switch between them pretty easily

Comment: In this case, I created a new account and wanted to know if it is possible to add an existing monitor profile (however, to another account). Is it possible?

Comment: So, you want to be able to see the information from the old account in the new one? In this case you need to log into the old account and go to Admin -> user management and add your new account to that old account

Comment: Thanks ! I'll need to do it.